# Calculate variance from the fixed parameters of a joint model for longitudinal data with informative times

Tags: mixed-model, expectation-maximization

I am trying to get the EM algorithm for a joint model for longitudinal data with informative time measurements.
In the simpler case, I am considering the following model

$$Y_{ij}=X_{ij}^T\gamma+U_i+Z_{ij},$$

with $Z_{ij}\sim N(0, \tau^2)$ and $U_i \sim N(0,\nu^2)$.

The visit process is defined by the intensity function

$$\lambda(t_{ij}|U_i)=\exp\left\lbrace \alpha+\beta U_i\right\rbrace.$$

I already computed the parameters $\theta=(\gamma,\nu^2,\tau^2,\alpha,\beta$), but now I wanted to calculate the standard errors for the $\gamma$ parameters. So I have to calculate $Var(\hat{\gamma})$, with

$$\gamma=(X^T X)^{-1}X^T(Y-E_c[U]).$$

$E_c[U]$ represents $E(U)|Y, R,\theta'$ - the expected value of the complete data given the observed data and the current estimate of the parameters - approximated by a 2-point Gaussian-Hermite quadrature. $R$ denotes the inter-arrival times of the time process.

How to deduce the $Var(\hat{\gamma})$ formula?